# Real commutative Banach algebra with identity

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, banach-algebras

I am looking for example of real commutative Banach algebra with identity which does not admit a nonzero real multiplicative linear functional

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbb{C}$ with it's usual structure of real commutative unital Banach algebra. If $\varphi:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is linear and multiplicative, then $\varphi(1)=\varphi(1)^2$, hence $\varphi(1)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$. Since $-\varphi(1)=\varphi(-1)=\varphi(i^2)=\varphi(i)^2$, then $\varphi(1)$ cannot be equal to $1$. Therefore, $\varphi(1)=0$ and $\varphi=0$.